# python : FTP with TarFile

Tags: python

i have the following code, and i want to know how can supress the error, i tried some google search but with no sucess.

```
def backup_system(dirs):
    """ Funcao para fazer backup das confs do systema """ 
    os.walk("/")
    try:
        tar = tarfile.open("/home/backup/system/system_backup_%s.tgz" % today, "w:gz")
        for dir in system_dirs:
            tar.add(dir,recursive=True)
    finally:
        tar.close()
    print tar 
    ftp_put(tar)


def ftp_put(file):
    """Funcao para fazer upload dos arquivos para FTP"""
    conn = ftplib.FTP(ftp_server, backup_user, backup_password)
    f = open(file, 'r')
    conn.storbinary("STOR ", f)
    try:
        f = open(file, 'r')
        conn.storbinary("STOR ", f)
        f.close()
    finally:
        conn.quit()
```

Well, it's ok, except for the fact that this code returns error with the ftplib. It says that expect str, but found tarfile.
Many thanks.

Right, here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/backup.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/backup.py", line 78, in main
    backup_system(system_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/bin/backup.py", line 42, in backup_system
    ftp_put(tar)
  File "/usr/local/bin/backup.py", line 55, in ftp_put
    f = open(file, 'rb')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, TarFile found
```

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? You didn't even post what line the error occured on. I am guessing that it's line 11 though.

Comment: @DontCare4Free yes i can, i will edit the question with the error. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: im having a problem accessing the server, err. I will update soon as i can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To augment Ignacio's answer I updated your backup_system a bit, hopefully this should do the trick.

```
def backup_system(dirs):
    """ Funcao para fazer backup das confs do systema """ 
    os.walk("/")
    tar_name = "/home/backup/system/system_backup_%s.tgz" % today
    try:
        tar = tarfile.open(tar_name, "w:gz")
        for dir in system_dirs:
            tar.add(dir,recursive=True)
    finally:
        tar.close()
    print tar 
    ftp_put(tar_name)
```

Comment: it seems that f = open(file, "rb") do not accept TARFILE as input

Comment: @Simão, as has been stated multiple times, don't pass the tar file itself to ftp_put. Instead, pass the name of the tar.gz file you want to send.

Answer (score 4):

`tar` is a `tarfile.TarFile`, but `open()` expects a string to use as a filename.

Comment: yes, it works making the file .tgz right, but when i try to upload to ftp ... the error occurs

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams well, i put the stacktrace. So, what is the right way to do this with open ? Convert it right before call ftp function ?

Comment: @Simão, added my own answer with an example of how to do this correctly.